# High-Frequency Transformer

Tags: transformer, dc-dc-converter, power-electronics

I am  trying  to simulate a Dual Active Bridge DC-DC Converter in Matlab / Simulink

So, I need to design a High-frequency Transformer with these characteristics:
Vin = 350 V , Vout = 800 V, Pmax= 10 KW ,f= 250 KHz

In order to have an accurate simulation, I have to know the Winding Resistance as well as the leakage and magnetizing inductance.

My first thought was to choose a commercial High-frequency Transformer and then search in the datasheet in order to find the parameters that I need.
Unfortunately, although that I found a lot of transformers suitable for my application, these parameters were not included in the datasheet.

So is there anybody that may have these parameters for a High-Frequency Transformer with Vin = 350 V , Vout = 800 V, Pmax= 10 KW ,f= 250 KHz)

If no , is there a way to calculate the parameters that I need using the Vin, Vout, Pmax and f?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I add a schematic of the Dual Active Bridge Converter

[image]

Comment: What is your core material? What are its losses? What volume of core will you pay for? What heating can the core tolerate, with or without forced-air cooling? You must respect the Curie Temperature of some materials.

Comment: Post a schematic to what you call a "Dual Active Bridge DC-DC Converter" so that the transformer can at least be seen in a circuit (even if it is somewhat idealized).

Comment: @analogsystemsrf  At the moment I just want to do some simulations in Simulink. So I just need to know approximately the parameters that I said in my question.
For instance, the Rprimary is 1 Ω ? 1 mΩ ? 1 μΩ?

Comment: @Andyaka I added a schematic.

Comment: Number of turns and wire diameters can be calculated easily, but calculating leakage inductances is quite hard, because it depends on a lot of unknown (i.e. to be measured) parameters. So, measuring leakages on a real transformer is the best way to go. For winding resistance, in addition to the wire diameter, the length of wire should be known. And, as you might guess, it depends on the coil former, winding structure and some other mechanical parameters.

Comment: Off the shelf - no. Find out - yes! Design the transformer and you will have pretty much all parameters except for leakage inductance which will be tricky to estimate unless you are ok with a rough figure.